Cómo solucionar (activemq) Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[activemq:queue:cola_ejemplo] apache camel
Estoy tratando de solucionar un problema que me surge dentro de apache camel al momento de enviar un mensaje al servidor activemq.
La siguiente imagen ilustra el error que me da

El código luce algo así
public class ObjectToActiveMq {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        //Creamos y obtenemos una conexión para ActiveMq
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                .to("activemq:queue:cola_ejemplo");
            }
            
        });

        context.start();

        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:start", new Date());
        context.close();
    }
}

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.
